# I want to pass brand name one by one as a paramater in rtk query and want to get total models of cars of that brand

Tags: reactjs, api, loops, rtk-query

I am working on a project in react and using rtk query. I need to get data from one api and pass it to the other api and get number of cars based on brand name but my first api is an array of brand names and rtk query does not work with loops. Kindly suggest me a way in which I can dynamically get no. Of cars displayed in my table agaist the brand name.
Thanks in advance.

```
import 'react' from React;

function Cars(){

const {data:branddata} = useGetAllBrands();

//need to get brandname dynamically
const {data:carsdata} = useGetCarsByBrandName(brandname);

const column = [
{header:"Brand Name",assesor:"col1"},
{header:"Total No. Of Car",assesor:"col2"}];
const data = [];
if(branddata){
 branddata.map((d)=>{
  col1:d.brandname,
  //col2: need to get total no. Of cars based on col1 value
}
return(
<>
<Table column={column} data={data}/>
</>
)

}

export default Cars;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If column can render a component, try creating a new component for `col2` that returns no. of cars and to this component pass `brandname` as prop.

Move `useGetCarsByBrandName(brandname)` inside new component. This way each row will render this custom component which fetches data it needs based on `brandname`

[Edit]

You can't call RTK Query hook inside `map`. It's against rules of hooks. But if new component is created, hook can be called inside this new component which can be assigned to a column to display data.

*Assuming data here is total number of cars by brand name that needs to be dispalyed in col2*

```
const CarsByBrandName = ({brandName}:props)=>{
   const {data} = useGetCarsByBrandName(brandName);
  return (data&& <p>data</p>)
}
```

In your `Cars` component, update `branddata.map` as below

```
branddata.map((d)=>{
  col1:d.brandname,
  col2: <CarsByBrandName brandName={d.brandname} />
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still I cannot understand how will I pass brandname in useGetCarsByBrandName() coz brandname will be an array and we cannot put rtk query in loop or function.

Comment: You are reading `brandname` from 1st api result inside map function using `d.brandname`. Isn't `d.brandname` a string?

Comment: Yes it is string but that's my ques how can i get that string because for example if first api returns four brandnames how would I pass them one by one in such a way that I get the right no. Of cars against the brandname in table. If I use map then also I can't put rtk query inside it.

Comment: I've updated the answer with code

Comment: Thank you it worked. Have been busy lately so forgot to accept your answer.